# Flatlist data dissapears after trying to search something with textinput

Tags: javascript, react-native

In my app there is a textinput and a flatlist the data is in a local file and not from a server. The problem is that when i search something the data in the flatlist disapears, the only way to get back the data to showing again is to reload the app. What is wrong with the code?
This is how far i've come with the code.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  View,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  FlatList,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import { useTheme } from '../Data/ThemeContext';
import DataBase from '../Data/DataBase';

export default function Home() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
  const [filteredDataSource, setFilteredDataSource] = useState(DataBase);
  const [masterDataSource, setMasterDataSource] = useState([]);

  const { colors } = useTheme();

  const searchFilterFunction = (text) => {
    if (text) {
      const newData = masterDataSource.filter(function (item) {
        const itemData = item.name ? item.name : '';
        const textData = text;
        return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
      });
      setFilteredDataSource(newData);
      setSearch(text);
    } else {
      setFilteredDataSource(masterDataSource);
      setSearch(text);
    }
  };

  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          margin: 15,
          borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
          padding: 10,
          borderRadius: 10,
          borderColor: colors.text,
        }}
        onPress={() => getItem(item)}>
        <Text style={{ color: colors.text, fontWeight: '700' }}>
          {item.name}
        </Text>
        <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>{item.company}</Text>
        <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>{item.gluten}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  const getItem = (item) => {
    alert(item.extra);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.background }}>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          padding: 30,
        }}>
        <TextInput
          style={[
            {
              flex: 1,
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
              borderRadius: 10,
              shadowColor: '#888888',
              shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
              shadowOpacity: 0.8,
              shadowRadius: 2,
              elevation: 3,
            },
          ]}
          placeholder="Sök"
          placeholderTextColor="#000"
          onChangeText={(text) => searchFilterFunction(text)}
          value={search}
        />
      </View>
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={filteredDataSource}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          initialNumToRender={1}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          style={{ height: 470 }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

DataBase file with all the data

```
const DataBase = [
  {
    name: 'text text text text',
    company: 'text text text text',
    
  },
  {
    name: 'text text text text',
    company: 'text text text text',
    
  },
  {
    name: 'text text text text',
    company: 'text text text text',
  },
];

export default DataBase;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working Example: [Expo Link](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/6aae26)

Final App:

[image]

```
export default function Home() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

  const [masterDataSource, setMasterDataSource] = useState(DataBase);

  const { colors } = useTheme();

  let filteredDataSource = masterDataSource.filter((item) => item.name.includes(search))
  //  do this instead of creating new state:

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{
          margin: 15,
          borderWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
          padding: 10,
          borderRadius: 10,
          borderColor: colors.text,
        }}
        onPress={() => getItem(item)}>
        <Text style={{ color: colors.text, fontWeight: '700' }}>
          {item.name}
        </Text>
        <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>{item.company}</Text>
        <Text style={{ color: colors.text }}>{item.gluten}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  const getItem = (item) => {
    alert(item.extra);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.background }}>
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: 'row',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
          padding: 30,
        }}>
        <TextInput
          style={[
            {
              flex: 1,
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
              borderRadius: 10,
              shadowColor: '#888888',
              shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
              shadowOpacity: 0.8,
              shadowRadius: 2,
              elevation: 3,
              padding: 10,
            },
          ]}
          placeholder="Sök"
          placeholderTextColor="#000"
          onChangeText={(text) => setSearch(text)}
          value={search}
        />
      </View>
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={filteredDataSource}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          initialNumToRender={1}
          showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          style={{ height: 470 }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```